# Spotify Connect and Windows IoT

Tags: spotify, windowsiot

I'm currently trying to develop a living room speaker. There is a screen that allows you to select the music, play and pause music... So for the interface I use uwp applications (Universal Windows Programs). To execute it **I installed windows IoT os on a raspberry pi 2B+. I would like to know if it's possible to make this raspberry pi a spotify connect ?**

I found nothing on google so if anyone can help me it will be with pleasure.
Thanks

Comment: It's a Raspberry Pi 3 not 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a device in Spotify Connect directly via UWP however you could with a WebView use the [Spotify Web Playback SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/) and that can create a player with Spotify Connect you could control with your device using the API

Comment: Ok I will try this